# Дан двумерны массив MxN, заполненный случ числами от 1 до 4. Найти № строк, все элементы которых четные, eсли таких нет, то вывести сообщение об этом

Tags: c, массивы

Код работает, но я не понимаю как сделать, что бы сообщение вывелось один раз, а не на каждую строку

Дан двумерный массив MxN, заполненный случайными числами от 1 до 4. Найти номера строк, все элементы которых четные. Если таких нет, то вывести сообщение об этом.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Дан двумерный массив MxN, заполненный случайными числами от 1 до 4. 
//Найти номера строк, все элементы которых четные. 
//Если таких нет, то вывести сообщение об этом.

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    
    int i, j, n, m, rand(), EvenIntegerRow;
    printf("Введите размер массива, разделенный пробелом (строки и столбцы): ");
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    
    int mxn[n][m];  
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    //заполнение массива
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i) {
        for(j=0; j<m; ++j) {
            mxn[i][j] = 1 + rand() % 4;  
        }
    }
    // вывод массива
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i){
        for(j=0; j<m; ++j) {
            printf("%d\t", mxn[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
int count = 0;      // количество четных на текущей строке
// поиск строки четных элементов
    for(i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        
        for(j=0; j<m; ++j) 
        {
            if(mxn[i][j] % 2 == 0) 
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if(count==n)
        {
            EvenIntegerRow = i;
            printf("\nСтрока все элементы которой четные: %d", EvenIntegerRow);    
        }
        else
            printf("\nТаких строк нет"); 
        
    }
 
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто заведите флаг для проверки, если была найдена хотя бы 1 строка, то последнее условие никогда не выполнится и сообщение не выведется. Наоборот, если ни одной строки не найдено, то последнее условие выполнится.

```
  bool find = false;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {

        for (j = 0; j < m; ++j)
        {
            if (mxn[i][j] % 2 == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == n)
        {
            find = true;
            EvenIntegerRow = i;
            printf("\nСтрока все элементы которой четные: %d", EvenIntegerRow);
        }
    }
    if (!find)
    {
        printf("\nТаких строк нет\n");
    }
```